# Include a label for metadata purposes without aggregating on it

Tags: promql

I have a Gauge metric that indicates the error status of a variable number of **project** replications to **mirrors**:

- `project A` -> `project A Mirror 1` -> `project A Mirror 2`
- `project B` -> `project B Mirror 1` -> `project B Mirror 2`
- `...`

There is one value per mirror, per project, where `1` is a successful mirror and `0` is a failure. A `status` label includes a variable error message string if there was a failure, and a `type` label differentiates mirrors.

The full data for a single time series might look something like this:

```
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectA",status="ok",type="a"} 1
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectA",status="ok",type="b"} 1
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectB",status="Something went wrong: full error message",type="a"} 0
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectB",status="ok",type="b"} 1
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectC",status="ok",type="a"} 1
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectC",status="ok",type="b"} 1
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectD",status="ok",type="a"} 1
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectD",status="Something different went wrong: full error message",type="b"} 0
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectE",status="ok",type="a"} 1
mirror_info{instance="",job="mirror-status",path="projectE",status="ok",type="b"} 1
```

I want to be able to show a table like this:

```
| project  | status a                                 | status b                                           |
| -------  | --------                                 | ---------                                          |
| projectA | ok                                       | ok                                                 |
| projectB | Something went wrong: full error message | ok                                                 |
| ...      | ...                                      | ...                                                |
| projectD | ok                                       | Something different went wrong: full error message |
```

The issue I'm running into is that I can't aggregate on `path` without losing the `status`, and I can't include the `status` without getting a different entry for every single error message variant.

I'm too much of a beginner at PromQL to know if such a thing is even possible, and fully aware that Prometheus may not even be the right tool to use for this, however that particular requirement is beyond my control in this case.